# How can I let the text label in FloatingActionButton.extended word wrap without specifying its width?

Tags: flutter, button, text, layout, material-design

I tried everything including `Expanded`, `Container` (with `double.infinity` with or not), `Wrap`, `FractionallySizedBox`. And it always either shows me the overflow issue, completely crashes, or makes the text vanish.

If I use a `SizedBox` with a specific `width` then word wrapping works. But I don't want to constrain the width arbitrarily.

Here's what the code looks like now:

[image: flutter material dialog with an overflowing text button]

When you run the code, tap the `+` button to trigger the dialog at https://dartpad.dev/?id=512790bee6ee8f5a14f1e6d4fc6b47f1

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              // title: const Text('Popup example'),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(children: [
                    FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.nordic_walking),
                      label: const Text(
                        'j laskdjfla sdlf alsdk flakj flkasj dlk jalsd asdf asdlf asldkj fal ads aa da s ',
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  ]),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 80,
                        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                          heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                          label: const Text(
                            'asdfasdjlfk asdk jfla sdflak sdfla df.a sdf askd.jf .aksd ak jf.a ksjdja .kja. jad.k j sda jflaksd jlas jdlfka sdlkfja lskdfjlak sdjlfkj asldkf jalskjflkjasd lkj faljd lasjlk jdlkaj s',
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ))
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to wrap your `label` widget in a `ConstrainedBox` widget, set the maxWidth property, and use row with Expanded child.

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: UniqueKey(),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.nordic_walking),
              label: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: maxWidth,
                ),
                child: const Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'asdfasdjlfk asdk jfla sdflak sdfla df.a sdf askd.jf .aksd ak jf.a ksjdja .kja. jad.k j sda jflaksd jlas jdlfka sdlkfja lskdfjlak sdjlfkj asldkf jalskjflkjasd lkj faljd lasjlk jdlkaj s',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
```

To get the maxWidth, we need to make some calculations.

```
final size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
final double paddingScaleFactor = _paddingScaleFactor(MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context));
final EdgeInsets effectivePadding = MediaQuery.viewInsetsOf(context) +
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 40 *
                paddingScaleFactor, // inset padding of dialog, left and right (20 + 20)
          );
 final maxWidth = size.width - // width of screen
          effectivePadding.left - // left padding of dialog
          effectivePadding.right - // right padding of dialog
          24 * 2 * paddingScaleFactor - // left and right padding of button
          48; // width of icon
```

Get padding scale factor

```
double _paddingScaleFactor(double textScaleFactor) {
final double clampedTextScaleFactor =
    clampDouble(textScaleFactor, 1.0, 2.0);
// The final padding scale factor is clamped between 1/3 and 1. For example,
// a non-scaled padding of 24 will produce a padding between 24 and 8.
return lerpDouble(1.0, 1.0 / 3.0, clampedTextScaleFactor - 1.0)!;
}
```

Make sure to handle the height as required.

Comment: I tested your suggestion at https://dartpad.dev/?id=13a957766549a2082c20cfb3919f90b1 and it seems to make the pixel overflow even bigger. And the text still does not wrap.

Comment: It is working. You forgot to wrap your SizedBox with Expanded widget.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the gist with an `Expanded` wrapping the `SizedBox`. Now there isn't a pixel overflow. Interesting that the text wraps or not based on how wide the screen is when the dialog pops up. It looks broken in the case that the screen is wide enough to contain the text, in that case the icon and text float to the left of the button.